# make button grow vertically to fit content, not horizontally

Tags: css

I have the desired behavior in my local setup, but once I imported into Wordpress, things changed subtly and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Essentially, I just want to button to grow vertically rather than horizontally. Currently, when the button has too much text, it flows outside of the div.

The included pic shows the desired local behavior next to the one that's overflowing.

--I have gone line by line through the "Computed" styles, but don't see what's causing it. It doesn't seem to be overflow-x/y, one of the few differences

note that in the picture, the messed-up button is using a different font, but I changed that and it's still not fitting correctly.

[image: two screenshots of the divs in question]

Comment: try add `white-space: pre-wrap;`, try in developer tools, if it get dashed then add !important.

Comment: We need some code to see what the problem is

Comment: @RapSherlock if you turn this to an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add `white-space: pre-wrap;`, try in developer tools, if it get dashed then add `!important`.

here more reference for :

- pre-wrap in [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

> pre-wrap Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at
> newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

- !important in [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

> The `!important` exception When an important rule is used on a style
> declaration, this declaration overrides any other declarations.
> Although technically `!important` has nothing to do with specificity, it
> interacts directly with it. Using `!important`, however, is bad practice
> and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by
> breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets. When two
> conflicting declarations with the `!important` rule are applied to the
> same element, the declaration with a greater specificity will be
> applied.
>
> Some rules of thumb:
>
> ```
> - Always look for a way to use specificity before even considering !important
> - Only use !important on page-specific CSS that overrides foreign CSS (from external libraries, like Bootstrap or normalize.css).
> - Never use !important when you're writing a plugin/mashup.
> - Never use !important on site-wide CSS.
> ```

credit goes to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting display property like following:

```
.button-class {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

You need to set display to "block" or "inline-block" in order to pass your desired width and make css follow it.

Comment: this worked for the button, but the text still overflowed